# Class cast exception using CXF under Java 11

Tags: java, cxf

I am in the process of converting an application which runs under Java 8 to Java 11. It uses the Apache CXF library for web services with attachments. As the enterprise libraries have been removed from the 11 JRE I have added the required libraries to the classpath (SAAJ, JAXB etc). Now when it runs I get the following exception

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to class javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl is in module java.xml of loader 'bootstrap'; javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJStreamWriter.adjustOverlaidNode(SAAJStreamWriter.java:64)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter.writeStartElement(OverlayW3CDOMStreamWriter.java:132)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.writeSoapEnvelopeStart(SoapOutInterceptor.java:122)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:81)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:61)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:133)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy261.dpSrequestToken(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone know why the default message construction appears to create an instance of a class that doesn't implement the required SOAPElement interface?

Answer (score 0):

Please wait for CXF 3.3.x to use Java 11. The community is currently working on it. You can use JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20CXF%20AND%20text%20~%20%22jdk11%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC to track the status.